# Range error when sorting

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have some code that reads all the files in a folder and displays them in a column in Excel.  After it gets the data, I want VBA to sort this data, but I keep getting a:

> Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed.

Note, I'm ONLY interested in sorting column A. Depending for the type of file I'm searching for, there could be 10 results, or there could be 100+ results.

I have a button called "gatherInfo", once this button is clicked it *gathers info* (can't show you that part of the code due to confidentiality of folder names and file names). The gathering of information works just fine, but the sorting doesn't.

```
Private Sub GatherInfo_Click()

   *gets info*

   Cells(1, 1).Select
   Cells(1, 1).Select
   Sheets("Data").Select

   Dim oneRange As Range
   Dim aCell As Range

   Set oneRange = Range("A1:A100")
   Set aCell = Range("A1")

   oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Example of files I'm trying to sort in order of name:

```
 - cat01.exe
 - cat07.exe
 - cat02.exe
 - cat11.exe
 - cat03.exe
```

Would like it to look like:

```
 - cat01.exe
 - cat02.exe
 - cat03.exe
 - cat07.exe
 - cat11.exe
```

**EDIT: changed code around a bit, got rid of the Select statements, error went away but it is still NOT sorting**

```
Private Sub GatherInfo_Click()

   *gets info*

   Dim oneRange As Range
   Dim aCell As Range

   Set oneRange = Range("A1:A100")
   Set aCell = Range("A1")

   oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

**EDIT02: i believe my issue is the actual file names, closing out my question**

Comment: Get rid of `Cells(1,1).Select` (both occurences).

Comment: the error is gone which is a plus, but it's not sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this works:

```
Public Sub GatherInfo_Click()

   '*gets info*

   Cells(1, 1).Select
   Cells(1, 1).Select
   Sheets("Data").Select

   Dim oneRange As Range
   Dim aCell As Range

   Set oneRange = Range("A1:A100")
   Set aCell = Range("A1")

   oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Check the spelling of **Data**

Comment: The spelling is correct, i took out the select parts of the code to simplify it. gets rid of the error, but it's still not sorting.

Comment: @pts2800 are you sure it is sorting the correct worksheet? Because this works when I test it.

Comment: @DavidZemens interesting, just tried with the cat example, and it worked, must be something to do with the file names i'm using... thanks for the help!

Comment: @pts2800 it is probably a good idea that the example data you provide should be representative of the actual data you're working with...